# Synchronize two ListView positions when you scroll from both list views Android

Tags: android

I have two ListViews. Is there any way to synchronize the position of ListViews when I scroll both the Lists

Comment: I have a working sollution please check this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906263/how-to-syncronisize-two-listview-positions/16168749#16168749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this in your second list view: [smoothScrollToPosition(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

And in your first ListView you could use a [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) and check the first visible item with [getFirstVisiblePosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition%28%29).

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: have you tried with the above solution .since i didnt get scrolling with the same idea

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method to get the scroll position of your first listView-

```
    private void saveListScrollPosition()
    {
    // save index and top position
    index = _listview1.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View view = _listview1.getChildAt(0);
    top = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop();
    }
```

And scroll the second listView to that position with-

```
// restore
    _listview2.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```