# Sync 2 ListViews by Scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to syncronisize two Listview positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906263/how-to-syncronisize-two-listview-positions)
>   [Sync 2 ListViews while Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909196/sync-2-listviews-while-scrolling)

I have two `ListViews`. Is there any way to `synchronize` the position of `ListViews` when I scroll any one of the Lists. I am implementing an `AbsListView.OnScrollListener`, registering to the `ListView`.

When the `ListView` is scrolled, the `onScroll()` method of `OnScrollListener` will be triggered, then i call `smoothScrollToPosition()`. But it don't work properly.

Can someone provide me any code example for this?...I Only want to Scroll One `ListView` and the other `ListView` moves synchronously. If you wan to know why i am using 2 `ListView` is because i am trying to make my own compound control that behaves as a `DataGridView` with a column fixed and headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
if( this.getScrollY() != otherList.getScrollY() )
    otherList.setScrollY( this.getScrollY() );
```

In the onScroll method of the onScrollListener. The above is pretty rough.

Comment: Actually, you want to use otherList.setSelectionFromTop(). getScrollY() refers to the scroll of the entire view, not the listview's contents. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2133897/854864)

Comment: getScrollY() is always 0 for a listview